# NSNumberFormatter customize?

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa

I wish to use NSNumberFormatter to merely attached a percent ('%') to the supplied number WITHOUT having it multiplied by 100.

The canned `kCFNumberFormatterPercentStyle` automatically x100 which I don't want.

For example, converting 5.0 to 5.0% versus 500%.

Using the following:

```
NSNumberFormatter *percentFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[percentFormatter setNumberFormat:@"##0.00%;-##0.00%"];
```

But 'setNumberFormat' doesn't exist in NSNumberFomatter.

I need to use this NSNumberFormatter for my Core-Plot label.

How can I customize NSNumberFormat?

Ric.

Answer (score 3):

Source: Apple's NSDecimalNumber reference.

Apparently I hinted the answer by saying that I didn't want the output to be 100x.
I'm working with a NSDecimalNumber which has the 'setMultiplier' method.

So, after I used the canned kCFNumberFormatterPercentStyle for the formatter, 
I used 'setMultiplier:1' as follows:

```
 NSNumberFormatter *percentFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
 [percentFormatter setNumberStyle:kCFNumberFormatterPercentStyle];
 [percentFormatter setMultiplier:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `setMultiplier` to prevent it from multiplying by 100?

```
NSNumberFormatter *percentFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[percentFormatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterPercentStyle];
[percentFormatter setMultiplier:1];
```

If adding the percent sign is all you need to accomplish, an alternative using `NSNumberFormatter`would be:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.2f%%", [myNumber doubleValue]];
```

And you should adjust the precision specifier (3.2) to suit the number of digits you want to display.